# Android app admin generating a particular code

Tags: android, performance, security, installation, apk

I'm developing a restaurant application in which a common build is there.At the time of initial installation, using admin privilege a particular restaurant code is generated. Using that restaurant code only the app can be activated.No one can install that instance in another device.

For this criteria, what all security conditions shall I follow. Please help me with sample code.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide me suggestion

Comment: Your question is more than a little unclear... can you be more specific about what you are actually asking? And provide some example code for the problem you're inquiring about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Create a licence file which can contain all the licenses on the backend

whenever user installs the app a screen would asked for a particular license

that licences could be validated over server if the user is authorised he can access all the feature.

once a license have been used it would be removed from the list so that it can not be used further also you can bind that particular key with users mobile number or iMEi number

here you can distribute license over email or sms for the registered user